# Convert text smilies to emoticons in android

Tags: android, emoji

I am working on android app and to show Emoji Keyboard I have used the below library https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon
Which gives me the Emoji keyboard using which I can type Emoji icons and show them.

But If I type anything like this :) ;) from keyboard, I want to convert these symbols also in Emoji Icons, so please can anyone help me in doing so.

Please post here if anyone have already done this, it would be a great help.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: if the emoji's are svg strings, then you could technically parse every keyboard input before submission, then replace any smily strings with emoji svg strings

Comment: I am having a simple string hello  :) and I do not have any images saved to show emoticons, what Logic should I use here?
Can you please explain ?

Comment: if you take a look at the lib's source code you can see that the emojicons are all special characters https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/blob/master/lib/src/github/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/emoji/People.java, all you have to do is add textwatcher to your edittext and `onTextSubmit` just replace all the smily faces with respective emojicon characters

Comment: But How can I extract smiley faces from the given string, should I first store all these symbols anywhere in app and check if the symbol occurs in string.

Comment: yes you need to either write a regex that only matches all smiley strings (which is impossible I think) or keep a static array in your code with all the smiley face strings you want to replace, but I think this is a very slow solution if you use regex its fast, but if you use the array way its slow

Comment: Ok Bhargav, thank you so much for all your guidance. I will try to find out solution for this and will post here once I will figure it out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Emoji also represented as special UTF-8 text so you have to replace all :) ;) with emoji:
[Emoji encoding](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)